# Apache Spark Session: IOException: mkdir of (path) failed

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I am testing the new version of Apache Spark 2.0, by trying to make use of structured streaming functionalities, using a very simple code that creates a Dataset with streaming data, and then prints the created dataset.
This is the code I have:

```
    SparkSession mySession= SparkSession.builder().appName("ProcessData").master("local[*]").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","System.getProperty(\"user.dir\")/warehouse").getOrCreate();
    Dataset<Row> measurements=mySession.readStream().format("socket").option("host","localhost").option("port",5556).load();
    StreamingQuery printDataset=measurements.writeStream().format("console").start();
    printDataset.awaitTermination();
```

The problem is I get an  IOException: mkdir of (temporary directory) failed.
Can someone help me with this issue? Thank you so much.

This is the full ERROR that shows up:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: mkdir of C:/Users/Manuel%20Mourato/AppData/Local/Temp/temporary-891579db-0442-4e1c-8642-d41c7885ab26/offsets failed
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.primitiveMkdir(FileSystem.java:1065)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.mkdir(DelegateToFileSystem.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFs.mkdir(FilterFs.java:197)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:730)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$4.next(FileContext.java:726)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext.mkdir(FileContext.java:733)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog$FileContextManager.mkdirs(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.<init>(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:57)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.<init>(StreamExecution.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryManager.startQuery(StreamingQueryManager.scala:251)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:287)
at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamWriter.start(DataStreamWriter.scala:231)
```

Answer (score 0):

May be try this way?

```
SparkSession mySession= SparkSession.builder().appName("ProcessData").master("local[*]").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir",System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/warehouse").getOrCreate();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and although it makes the code more "clean", it didn't solve my issue. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Why you use System.getProperty in string? 
Also, please check if such folder exists, i.e.:

```
val tempDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
val path = tempDir + "/warehouse";

SparkSession mySession= SparkSession.builder().appName("ProcessData").master("local[*]").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", path).getOrCreate();
```

Also please check if you have write permission to this path. It should be good if you manually create warehouse dir and set permissions - you will be sure that everything is ok with it

Edit: Got it! 
At first, you should check write permissions to AppData/Local/Temp, as it is standard temporary directory.

This error is caused by [OffsetLog](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/988c71457354b0a443471f501cef544a85b1a76a/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/StreamExecution.scala#L134). You can change directory in which log will be created [by adding](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/a79838bdeeb12cec4d50da3948bd8a33777e53a6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/StreamingQueryManager.scala#L204) `option("checkpointLocation", ...)`

Comment: I have checked, and indeed the path exists and I have permission to write in it. BUT, there is something I should mention: this  IOException is not trying to make a directory in the val `path`, it's trying to make a directory in a different folder (.../AppData/Local/Temp). Is this normal?

Comment: No, it's not. I will search in Spark code where it is using temporary directory

Comment: Thank you so much. I included the full error above, it might help.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't work :/ . I did what you said and added `option("checkpointLocation", path_to_desktop)`, for example, and the same error shows up with any new path I choose, so `IOException: mkdir of path_to_desktop/offsets failed`
So strange.

Comment: @manuelmourato It's very weird. One more option - can you set this location to folder without space in name? Maybe space is making some problems

Comment: That was my thought too but no, same thing happens. `StreamingQuery` is an experimental class (says so in the API), it might be a bug or something similar...

Comment: It's not a problem with StreamingQuery, but with underlying Hadoop FileSystem implementation or some components that this library is using

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you also set your own checkpoint directory in config which has write permission, one way is to create checkpoints directory in same application code e.g.,

```
.config("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", "C:\\sparkApp\\checkpoints\\")
```